# I am struggling understand how to differentiate the self financial portfolio

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

The self financing portfolio is given by:

$V_t$ = $a_t$$S_t$ + $b_t$$\beta_t$

where $dS_t$ = 2$S_t$dt + 4$S_t$d$B_t$ and $a_t$ = -t and $b_t$ = $\int_0^tS_u du$ and $\beta_t$ = 1 hence

$V_t$ = -t$S_t$ + $\int_0^tS_u du$

I believe we are suppose to use the chain rule and get the answer:

d$V_t$ = -t d$S_t$ - $S_t$dt + $S_t$dt

But I am not sure how to use the chain rule here and differentiate the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the the product rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

We have:

$$\frac {dV_t}{dt} = \frac {d}{dt}(-tS_t)+\frac {d}{dt}\int_0^tS_udu=\left(-S_t-t\frac{dS_t}{dt}\right) + S_t$$

Giving:

$$dV_t = -tdS_t-S_tdt+S_tdt$$

Comment: I am still a bit confused with the integral part. Is it possible to explain it to me in a bit more detail? Thank you!

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that
$$\frac {d}{dt} \int_a^t f(u)du = f(t)$$ for any constant $a$.